# Java's ByteBuffer nearest counterpart in C#?

Tags: c#, memorystream, bytebuffer

Currently looking to interface a Java and a C# application. In Java I can use `getShort()`, `getFloat()` etc, to get various different data types from the buffer.

In C# I am using a `MemoryStream`, but there is only a single `get()` function. Does anybody know of a datatype or even a class that would mimic this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your `MemoryStream` in a `BinaryReader`:

```
using(var reader = new BinaryReader(yourStream)) {
   int someInt = reader.ReadInt32();  
}
```

The `BinaryReader` can be found in the `System.IO` namespace.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details on which methods you can use. Keep in mind that the methods follow the pattern of Read + the CLR type. So `ReadInt32()` for int, `ReadUInt16()` for short, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the `BinaryReader` class, which can read from any stream.

You can also use `BitConverter`, which operates directly on byte arrays.